# Large excel file, I'm trying to find duplicates and copy the rest of the cells across the duplicate to the duplicate it finds

Tags: excel, formula

I have a large excel file, it has 65,000 parts, those part numbers are in column A. Then it has several columns of important info next to the part number (B is retail price, C is my cost, D is the weight, E description and so on until J)
I was just given a list of 16,000 new parts, they are superceeded from old parts, all the new list tells is new part number in column A and old in column B.

So what I can't figure out is how to tell excel if B65001 matches anything in column A1-A65000 then copy the information from the columns next to that A cell into the columns next to this duplicate.

I hope that makes sense?

Please help

Comment: Use the `MATCH` function...

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- Put the list of new parts in a new sheet (let's call this "Sheet2")
- Sort this by column A (required for the VLOOKUP function)
- Insert a column next to A in the original sheet
- Put the formula `=ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet2!$A:$B, 2, FALSE), $A2, VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet2!$A:$B, 2, FALSE))` in column B2 of the original sheet (the new column, and I'm assuming you have headers), and fill it down
- Copy this new column and paste it over itself, but select Paste Values from the `Ctrl` paste options menu. This will get rid of the formula and solidify the new part number as text.
- Delete the old A column and the new B column will take its place.
- Delete Sheet2 if desired.

*The formula in layman's terms: Excel will search for the old part number in Sheet2. If not found, it will produce an error, and just use the old number. If found, it will use the value next to the old part number on Sheet2, the new part number.*

An explanation of [the `VLOOKUP` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx):

- The first argument is the value to search for. In this case the value in the A column of the same row (fill-down will automatically change the "2" accordingly)
- The second argument is the range to search in. Excel will look in the first column of this range for the value, and it MUST be sorted.
- The third argument is the 1-based index of the column to return. In this case, you want the second column.
- The final argument determines whether to return the nearest match (TRUE) or only exact matches (FALSE). You want the latter behavior.
- VLOOKUP in this mode will produce an error when a match is not found (specifically `#VALUE` when the value would come before the first instance of the table, or `#N/A` if the value is not found in exact-match mode)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Column in other sheet into you want to search Duplicates,, & write this simple formula but break the database in parts to avoid system delay,,

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8, $A2)>1, "Duplicate", "")
```

Use this array formula to count Duplicates,

```
=ROWS($A$2:$A$8)-SUM(IF( COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8)=1,1,0))
```